# integral with branch cut (depending on parameter)

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, residue-calculus, branch-cuts

I am trying to work out the integral
\begin{equation}
\int_{-1}^{+1} dx \frac{1+i \lambda x}{2(1-\lambda^2+2i \lambda x)^\frac{3}{2}},
\end{equation}
where $\lambda$ is real number and $i$ the imaginary unit. I am struggling with choosing an integral contour since the branch cut depends on $\lambda$. By numerical evaluations, I suspect for $|\lambda|<1$, the integral is 1, otherwise it is zero. 
Is there a proper way to do this integral?

Comment: the solution is very long

Comment: thank you again for your comment and interest.  Do you have any solution? I tried for some more time but still failed. Any advice or hint will be appreciated. (I reposted it as no answer showed up in last month.)

Comment: my Programm Mathematica has found a solution

Comment: is it possible that you could send me the code? my email address is pibitahxgz.fsmlhrp@my.tccd.edu

Comment: yes it is possible i will send you the given solution

Comment: it is sending now

Answer (score 0):

> Hint  First write your integrand as :

$$ \frac{1+i \lambda x}{2(1-\lambda^2+2i \lambda x)^\frac{3}{2}} =\frac{2 + \lambda^2+2i \lambda\color{red}{(x+\frac{i\lambda}{2}) }}{\color{blue}{4}(1+2i \lambda \color{red}{(x+\frac{i\lambda}{2}) })^\frac{3}{2}} 
\\:=\frac{2 + \lambda^2+2i \lambda\color{red}{z }}{\color{blue}{4}(1+2i \lambda \color{red}{z })^\frac{3}{2}} =f_\lambda(z) $$

Where, e set $\color{blue}{z =x+\frac{i\lambda}{2}},$ that is $dx =dz$.  Then, with the change of variables  $\color{blue}{z =x+\frac{i\lambda}{2}},$ we get,
$$I:=\int_{-1}^{+1} \frac{1+i \lambda x}{2(1-\lambda^2+2i \lambda x)^\frac{3}{2}} dx =\int_{\color{blue}{(-1, \frac{\lambda}{2})}}^{\color{blue}{(1, \frac{\lambda}{2})}} f_\lambda(z) dz  $$

From it is easy since can use the contour integral on the rectangle $ R_\lambda$with vertices's $(-1,0)-(1,0)-\color{blue}{(1, \frac{\lambda}{2})}-\color{blue}{(-1, \frac{\lambda}{2})}$

> **Remark** **This will very helpful**, $f_\lambda$ has one pole which is $z_\lambda = \frac{i\lambda}{2}$ and we have,

$$\color{brown}{\oint_{R_\lambda} f_\lambda(z) dz }= \color{blue}{\int_{-1}^{+1}f_\lambda(z) dz} +\int_{\color{blue}{(1,0)}}^{\color{blue}{(1, \frac{\lambda}{2})}} f_\lambda(z) dz +\int^{\color{blue}{(-1, \frac{\lambda}{2})}}_{\color{blue}{(1, \frac{\lambda}{2})}} f_\lambda(z) dz\\+\int^{\color{blue}{(-1,0)}}_{\color{blue}{(-1, \frac{\lambda}{2})}} f_\lambda(z) dz \\=-I+ \color{blue}{\int_{-1}^{+1}}\frac{2 + \lambda^2+2i \lambda\color{red}{x }}{\color{blue}{4}(1+2i \lambda \color{red}{x})^\frac{3}{2}}dx+ \int_{\color{blue}{(1,0)}}^{\color{blue}{(1, \frac{\lambda}{2})}} f_\lambda(z) dz+\int^{\color{blue}{(-1,0)}}_{\color{blue}{(-1, \frac{\lambda}{2})}}f_\lambda(z) dz    $$

Comment: I am little confused about the pole. Should it be $z=\frac{1}{2i\lambda}$ for $f_{\lambda}(z)$, rather than $z=\frac{i\lambda}{2}$?

Comment: @commutator I did not make any concret commutation.  May be you shrink the domain by epsilon to avoid the singularity and tell me if that works as well